# add results of a for loop after each iteration

Tags: c++, for-loop

I‘m having trouble with my for loop. I have a basic 2 times table that goes up from 1 to 10. (see below). I'm trying to add the result so that after every loop, `allResult` displays the values of all results added. it needs to show all results added after every loop. and I don't know how to go about it. A better description is the desired outcome commented in the code.

my Code...

```
int main(){

int allResult;

for( int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{

    int result = 2*i;

    cout << 2 << " times " << i << " = " <<  result << endl;

    // I want allResult to store results added. so after first loop, result = 2 so allResult = 2
    // after second loop, result = 4. so allResult should be 6. (results from 1 and 2 added)
    // after third loop, result = 6 so allResult should be 12. (results from 1, 2 and 3 added)
    // I'm trying to apply this to something else, that uses random numbers, so i cant just * result by 2.


}
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int allResult = 0;
for( int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    int result = 2*i;

    cout << "2 times " << i << " = " <<  result << endl;
    allResult += result;
    cout << "allResult: " << allResult << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int allResult = 0;
for( int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
     allResult += 2*i;  
    cout << 2 << " times " << i << " = " <<  2*i << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{

int allResult=0;

 for( int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {

      int result = 2*i;

      allResult=allResult+result; 
/*Initially allResult is 0. After each loop iteration it adds to its previous 
value. For instance in the first loop it was allResult=0+2, 
which made allResult equal to 2. In the next loop allResult=2+4=6. 
Third Loop: allResult=6+6=12. Fourth loop:allResult 12+8=20 and so on..*/

cout << 2 << " times " << i << " = " <<  result << endl;
  }

      system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote you or anything, but when you post code, you should try to (at least) get the indentation correct. This is just some small example, that's easy to understand, but even some more advanced snippets can be hard to understand when they aren't formatted in a propper way. Give it a try, it can help both you as a programmer and the community as a collective of people trying to understand your answers!